# Max Length Removal

Tags: string, python-3.x, data-structures

The problem is If there is “100” as a sub-string in the string, then we can delete this sub-string. The task is to find the length of longest sub-string which can be make removed?

```
s=input('')

i=0
if '100' not in s:
    print('0')
else:
    st=''

    while i<len(s)-2:
          if s[i:i+3]=='100':
             s= s.replace('100','')
             a=s.find('100')
             if a<=i:
                st=st+'100'
                i=a
             else:
                 st='100'
                 i=i+1



          else:

             i=i+1



    print(len(st))
```

for the input: 101001010000,this code is printing 9 instead of 12,
somehow the else part is not getting executed.. 
please someone help me out

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Why do you expect 12 from `101001010000`?

Answer (score 2):

`s.replace()` removes **all** occurrences of the substring, not just the first, and searching from the start.

This means that `'101001010000'.replace('100', '')` replaces *two* occurrences:

```
>>> '101001010000'.replace('100', '')
'101000'
```

but you count that as one replacement.

`str.replace()` takes a *third* argument, the number of replacements to be made, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*. If the optional argument *count* is given, only the first *count* occurrences are replaced.

Use that to limit the number of replacements.

Comment: but it will not work for 0111110011010011100000..the answer should be 6,this would print 12

Comment: @AbhinavVajpeyi why 6? I see 3 `100` substrings, and removing the last gives you another `100` substring. If that’s the wrong interpretation your question is unclear.

Comment: @AbhinavVajpeyi: I think I see what you mean; in the end the substitutions must have been limited to a substring, while the substitutions in that substring are not contiguous. Fine, so my proposed end solution doesn't apply, but I did correctly identify the issue with your approach. The final solution probably involves dynamic programming then.

Comment: This is the issue but I dont get it I found this problem on a website and I m not able to get the correct answer.So how would u approach for these problems? I m still confused